# How to log request and response activity on a python gRPC server?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I went through the [gRPC tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/) and got a successful response from the server.
However the server did not log anything from the command line. I was expecting to see something like request received - response sent with this status code. Similar to a django dev server or a local `http.server`:

```
Serving HTTP on 127.0.0.1 port 8000 (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2022 13:06:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2022 13:06:08] code 404, message File not found
```

What I tried with my gRPC server:

```
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG python greeter_server.py
```

That just gave strange output. I tried with `INFO` and received nothing when requests came in.

I saw on `grpc.server` there was the interceptor parameter:

> interceptors: An optional list of ServerInterceptor objects that observe
> and optionally manipulate the incoming RPCs before handing them over to
> handlers. The interceptors are given control in the order they are
> specified. This is an EXPERIMENTAL API.

How can I log requests and responses to the cli?

Answer (score 2):

In gRPC, Since The complete implementation of server and client are in your hands, it is upto the developer to create context-ful logging at both sides.

You can use [python logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) to print logs to cli. This is better than plain print() in many ways.

Ideally One can make server to print logs like.

1. Interface on which server is started on. (ip/hostname:port)
2. When a RPC call is received for a particular method.
3. Any intermediate info or debug logs in the method. Etc..,

In case you are looking for default logging in grpc which are just useful during development and not much helps in production, you can explore more about [gRPC traces](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md#L43-L44) using which you can control logging of different sub components of gRPC.